# Reading in csv file as command line argument, printing contents into output csv file

Tags: c, unix

I have a programming challenge where I have to read in a csv file as a command line argument (mine is called NameAgeGpa.csv and has multiple lines like: John, 19, 3.5 where the name is a string (max 50 char), the age(max 3 digits) is an int, and the gpa(max decimal with 2 digits after decimal point) is a double) and put the outputs into a new csv file. So far I have code for reading a csv file and printing the contents but that's not working. It's:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "parse.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

FILE *fp;
char buff[61];
struct people *p;
int n, i=0;

fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

n = atoi(argv[2]);

p = malloc(sizeof(struct people)*n);

while((fgets(buff, 61, fp) != NULL) && (i<n))
{
    p[i] = parse_csv_line(buff);
    ++i;
}
fclose(fp);
n = i;

for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("Name: %s, Age: %d, GPA: %e\n", p[i].name, p[i].age, p[i].gpa);
}

free(p);
return 0;
}
```

How could I get this to work and then put the contents in a new csv file?

Comment: I doubt it. You're assigning to `p[i]` and doing `free(p);`, smells fishy.

Comment: What if I remove it?

Comment: Could you post the output of that `printf`, and the code for `parse_csv_line`?

Comment: And the input file contents. How it's structured matters.

Comment: The csv file looks like this: Jack, 19, 3.6
Elizabeth, 17, 3.4
Ryan, 20, 2.33
Gertrude, 105, 5.0
Mattie, 21, 3.33
Molly, 52, 3.4
Steve, 51, 3
Steven, 58, 2.3 and after each person there's a new line

Comment: The printf doesnt output anything. I can't get my program to read my csv file on comman but this is my code for parsing #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "main.h"

    struct people parse_csv_line(char *line)
    {
 struct people p;
 char sep[2] = ",";
 char *token;

 token = strtok(line, sep);
 sprintf(p.name, "%s", token);
 token = strtok(line, sep);
 printf(p.age, "%s", token);
 token = strtok(line, sep);
 printf(p.gpa, "%s", token);

 return p;
    }

Comment: Please put code and sample input into the question. Not in comments. And don't forget to add definition of `struct people`

Comment: Please read the manual for `strtok`. What parameters shall be passed for first call and what parameters for further calls?

Comment: Have you sorted this ??